# Filter a database of locations due to user's current location with radius

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps

Hey guys i'm developing a specific android app which has a BigData of locations all over a country,i want to filter those locations due to user's current location with a radius.

To clarify my purpose my user is a car driver that chooses a random road on Google Map by specifying the start and the end point using Markers then i draw a road between those points using Google API

What i want to do is getting the locations from my database that lies on the selected road only so i thought of filtering my database locations due to user's current location and give it a radius which is the distance on the road(the distance between the two Markers chosen by the user) and start showing them on the map.

Note:I thought of comparing the locations in my database with the user's current location, If it is shorter than the radius(the distance between the two Markers) then i will add it to my filtration result

but i think it's a mess i have a BigData and it would take too much time to compare.

Is there any algorithm or API that Google Maps Provides for this problem that i can use to filter?
even if it's written in a web programming language i can create a web service to handle it and send it to my application.

Comment: `with a radius`. Calculating radius is time consuming. Or determine if points lay in a circle. Especially if you have many points. I would first select points wich are in a square. As that is only two subtractions.

Comment: from the beginning i didn't prefer a radius it's a big distraction for me as it's a road that i want the points on not a whole radius but i couldn't find another expression to state my question,can you tell me more about the Square method ?

Comment: You just look if abs(lat1-lat2)<deltalat. And if abs(lon1-lon2)<deltalon.

Comment: sry but i don't know where deltalat and deltalon came from ? what is there values ?

Comment: That is up to you. Say the points you are looking for should be within 100 m from the road. Then convert 100 m to deltalon and deltalat.

Comment: i thought of that method but wouldn't it take too much time comparing the whole database locations ?

Comment: What i said is that using a square takes less time then using a circle. Thats all.

Comment: Thanks alot i have find an awesome solution i will update my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find a solution for my problem

In my application i'm using Firebase as cloudbacked and fortunately it has a library that performs GeoQueries called GeoFire it's documentation is [here](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java)

It can create a query of all saved locations in Firebase due to a specific location by a radius in milliseconds which is what i really need

Answer (score 0):

Use KD-tree K nearst neighbours, to filter the points that are away from the car. and that's log N time complexity. but inserting into the tree is N*log N